# How to measure the IOS App Page load time

Tags: mobile, appium, performance-testing

I have an iOS app which took a lot of time to load the homepage and now after optimization the load time reduced. How do I measure the load time that the app took before and after optimization?

Answer (score 0):

If it is regarding server-client response, you can use JMeter. Otherwise RobotFramework with Appium is the best option to measure transition time between two pages. [RobotFramework with Appium](https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary)